# Insert data received from QGIS into MS SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssms, qgis

I am generating a layer in QGIS, containing point features which I need to display on a map. For that, I need to save latitude and longitude of those point features along with its details in MS SQL database.

I have tried multiple methods:

- Created database connection and added database table as a layer(eg-Layer1). Then, I provided local layer as an input to Layer1.
- I also tried executing sql query in DB Manager(QGIS), but I got this error in insert query: `Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS *****: 1 - near "INSERT": syntax error`
- I also tried to import vector layer to Database,then I got the following 
  error: `Error9-Provider virtual has no createEmptyLayer method`.

I need some guidance, so as to save the data into the table while creating the layer.

I need to save the layer's attribute so that I can generate the markers on the map created by uploading KML file (generated from QGIS). Any help is appreciated.

**Insert Statement**

```
INSERT INTO dbName.SchemaName.Tablename(Name, Longitude, Latitude) VALUES("abc",65.26,39.215)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the query that causes your syntax error?

Comment: It is a simple INSERT query:INSERT INTO dbName.SchemaName.Tablename(Name, Longitude, Latitude) VALUES("abc",65.26,39.215)

Comment: I removed my answer as you are still having an issue even after changing the string escape from " to '. Does the query run in Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes. The query runs perfectly in ssms

Answer (score 1):

In case, anyone is facing the same issue, I have resolved this. The steps are as follows:

1. Create a connection with the database and then add the desired table as layer. You'll be able to see a new layer in the Layer window.
2. Right click on the layer(exported from database table) and select 'Open Attribute Table' option.
3. Click 'edit' option from the toolbar, fill the data as needed and then, save the values by selecting save option from the toolbar.